# Is it possible to implement an equivalent syntax of (*x {\f(x)}) but the ordinate is specified first?

Tags: pstricks

PSTricks provides us with a useful syntax `(*x {\f(x)})` to specify a point with abscissa `x` and ordinate `\f(x)`. For example, let `\def\f(#1){#1+.5}`, a point `(1,1.5)` can be written as `(*1 {\f(x)})`.

I want to have the opposite way in which the ordinate is given first and the abscissa is calculated by the given expression `\g(y)`. For example, let `\def\g(#1){#1-.5}`, I want to have a point `(1,1.5)` but it has to be represented in the form `(**{\g(y)} 1.5)`.

Is it possible to implement it? I will give 4 bounties of 500 each if you can **implement** it.

Comment: What should `(+{\f(x)} 4)` return with `\def\f(#1){#1*#1}`? Functions happen to be non invertible.

Comment: If the function is `$f(x)=x^2$`, giving the value 4 doesn't determine `$x$` such that `$x^2=4$`. But even if the function is invertible, the inverse cannot generally be computed easily. Think to $f(x)=x+e^x$; only with numeric methods you can approximate the point where its value is 20.

Comment: god damn non invertible functions.

Comment: Finding `g(y)` which is the inverse of `f(x)` is beyond the scope of this question. Therefore this question was given as is without considering the issue of inverse function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\makeatletter
\define@boolkey[psset]{}[Pst@]{exchange}[true]{}
\psset{exchange=false}

\def\alg@@@coor#1 #2{%          algebraic PostScript code 
  \edef\pst@coor{%
    /x #1 def
    /Func (#2) AlgParser cvx def    
    x Func \ifPst@exchange exch \fi
    \tx@ScreenCoor }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\def\f(#1){#1^2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
\psline{->}(*2 {x^2})
\psline[exchange]{->}(*2 {x^2})
{\psset{exchange}\pnode(*2 {\f(x)}){A}}
\psline[linecolor=red](1,1)(A)(2;45)(*2 {\f(x)})
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or with the current version of pstricks.tex from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\def\f(#1){#1^2}
\def\y{2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,5)
\psline{->}(*2 {x^2})
\psline{->}(**{y^2} 2)
\psline[linecolor=red](1,1)(**{\f(y)} 2.2)(2;45)(*2 {\f(x)})

\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(+{sqrt(2),\f(x)}) 
\psline[linecolor=blue]{->}(+{sqrt(3)},{\f(x)}) 
\psline(+1,x+.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `(+x,f(x))` is not possible because TeX takes the first `)` as closing delimiter for the complete coordinate argument. This is the way how TeX reads arguments. You have to choose `({+x,f(x)})` or `(+x,{f(x)})`. It is the same as for optional arguments: `[foo=[x]]` must be written as `[foo={[x]}]`. However I uploaded a new version for the other problem.

Comment: `\psarc{->}{5}{0}{90}` is possible, but not`\psarc{5}{0}{90}`. Otherwise we have to do a special check for the first argument if it is an arrow or not.